# Sorting dictionary-represented graph edges by value/weight

Tags: python, graph

I had the following given representation of Graph Edges in python where the vertices are the keys and the edge weights are the values.

```
Edges = {(1,2):8.3 , (2,3): 4, (3,1):6}
```

I need to sort the Edges by weight for one application (Kruskal's algorithm). So given that dictionary is unsorted, I want to convert the Dictionary to a List of Tuples as below.

```
  Edges_List = [(1,2,8.3), (2,3,4), (3,1,6)]
```

These can be sorted by third element of tuple as key. I used this

```
 Edges_list = [(k,v) for k,v in Edges.items()]
```

but I get a nested tuple using this.

```
 Edges_List = [((1,2),8.3), ((2,3),4), ((3,1),6)]
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I create a tuple of three instead of a nested tuple that I get above?
2. Is there any other approach so that I can sort the Edges dictionary by weight which is a dictionary value apart from converting it into a list of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tuple unpacking as follows

```
>>> import operator
>>> Edges = {(1,2):8.3 , (2,3): 4, (3,1):6}
>>> Edges_list = [(k1,k2,v) for (k1,k2),v in Edges.items() ]
>>> Edges_list
[(1, 2, 8.3), (3, 1, 6), (2, 3, 4)]
>>> Edges_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
>>> Edges_list
[(2, 3, 4), (3, 1, 6), (1, 2, 8.3)]
```

If you want the sorted elements in a loop with your dictionary itself, you could use this

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(Edges, key=Edges.get):
...     # do stuff with edges
```

Notice that `k` and `v` are your co-ordinates in this case.

Comment: Thanks a small question in the documentation of itemgetter http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html I see  operator.itemgetter(*items) . What does '*' mean in python given that there are no pointers in python, right?

Comment: @vkaul11 `*` operator is used to unpack argument lists. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists explains it in great detail